# how to dynamically create campaign?

Tags: flurry, flurry-analytics

how to dynamically create a campaign url ? in campaign Summary
Dashboard I can only create a campaign with such url :
https://ad.apps.fm/wtHsmdflsmdfkmsdfkmsdlfkmsdsZcdxD_A

but i would like to create a campaign "on the fly" with url like :
https://ad.apps.fm?campaign_name={campaign_name} or something similar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dynamic Campaign creation is not  a supported feature. All campaigns must be manually created in the portal.

Comment: that a big problem :( no way to generate the campaign name "on the fly" :(